# how to make Firewall popup appear when I execute java application (or Jar)?

Tags: jar, firewall, java, firewall-access

I'm working on Java Application (game), and I need full internet access between server and client.

so I want to avoid getting blocked by the firewall by making this firewall popup appears when I execute the application for the first time.

the application will be shared in many PCs in my Class. so I cant set it manually for everyone.

[Please click on this link. This popup that I need to appear as soon as I execute the application (or JAR) for the first time in any PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVB4v.jpg)

Comment: Wouldn't it do this automatically? I think if a program is requesting any sort of network access from the computer windows handles it as a firewall request or am I wrong on this? Have you tried just running the program without making a firewall request?

Comment: @RileyCarney I'm note sure how does it work with Firewall, and I need it to appear just to avoid any kind of problem while the application is tested  infront of the Prof. and the class  ^^

Comment: Are you experiencing problems with the networking/connections in the application? I find that I never need to accept the firewall dialog with sockets in java applications...

Comment: As far as I know WIndows does ask automatically as soon as your program attempts to open a socket. The problem is that the users decision is then stored and remembered for the java excutable that is running the JVM (makes sense with normal executables, but not with the JRE).